# Saving the map state in android google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app i have markers that load up with the map and then i can add markers manually to the map at certain points.  Now my question is how can i save those manually added markers so when the users exits the app or navigate to a different activity and then returning to the map, then the markers should still be there.

I have tried a few examples given but that doesn't seem to work, only for when the screen rotates, but not for exiting the app and returning.

Could some one please point me in the right direction with an example i can follow?
Would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the post, and read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you need to write the data to a file or save it to a database and load it all again

Comment: @tyczj Would you be able to give an example?  Is it similar to using HashMap maybe?

Comment: see here about your storage options http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @jurgemaister the reason i am asking is because i don't have relevant code to post.  And don't really know where to start, hence why i am asking this question.

Comment: @tyczj Thanks, will go through that and see how i can do it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just to have the marker latitude and longitude stored somewhere offline/online so that when next time your app gets opened, your app fethces markers locations and you can add marker again to the map.

For storing data online, you just need to send information to server and fetch it back, whenever app is started again.

For offline storage, have a look at training from android developers : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Hope this helps..

Comment: Cool thanks for your answer.  Have had a look at that link and think sharedpreferences might be the trick?